# I want to use Database in Fragment ,It is showing error

Tags: android

I'm trying to open and write to a Sqlite database in Android. According to the log output, it's not opening. I know that my syntax isn't great and I should be saving from a Party object instead of straight from the fragment interface, but my focus is really on the the process. Any help would be super helpful!

```
public class TransactionFragment extends Fragment
     {        
    TextView tv1;




public TransactionFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    tv1=(TextView) container.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
 SQLiteDatabase db=openOrCreateDatabase("ExpensesDB",null);
    // Toast.makeText(AddTransactionActivity.this,s3.getSelectedItem().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    String q2="select * from Expense";
            Cursor e=db.rawQuery(q2,null);
            String data ="EMP Names:\n------------\n";
            while (e.moveToNext())
            {
                data=data+e.getString(1)+"\n";
            }
            tv1.setText(data);
    db.close();
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_transaction, container, false);
}
```

below is output file
[Log output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuTDI.png**)

Comment: The problem is inside the `openOrCreateDatabase()` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you should send the context to the builder...